# Vandermonde determinant: modulo

Tags: nt.number-theory, elementary-proofs

There is a lot of fascination with the [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and for many good reasons and purposes. My current quest is more of number-theoretic.

> **QUESTION.** Let $p\equiv 3$ (mod $4$) be a prime. What is the value of
>   $$\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq\frac{p-1}2}(j^2-i^2) \mod p?$$

Comment: This is a square root of the discriminant of the polynomial $X^{(p-1)/2}-1$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, although, as the situation with Gauss sums shows, it can be very interesting to know which of two square roots of a given element a number-theoretic construction gives us ….

Comment: The product is $1$ for the prime numbers $p\equiv 3$ modulo four up to $1000$.

Comment: Why only 3 mod 4?

Comment: For other values we get also other answers, for instance: `(5, 3), (13, 8), (17, 4), (29, 17), (37, 6), (41, 32), (53, 30), (61, 50), (73, 46), (89, 55), (97, 75)`, where the tuples are of the shape $p$, and the product value in $\Bbb F_p$. (All products above are of multiplicative order $4$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw this in [this recent arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07766) by Zhi-Wei Sun (Quadratic residues and related permutations and identities, version 6, equation (1.5)). I'll reproduce the proof in case it goes under further revisions. Every equality below is $\pmod{p}$. Start by factoring

$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le \frac{p-1}{2}}(j^2-i^2)=\prod_{1\le i<j\le \frac{p-1}{2}}(j-i)(j+i)$$
and noticing that
$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le \frac{p-1}{2}}(j-i)=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^{\frac{p-1}{2}-k}$$
$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le \frac{p-1}{2}}(j+i)=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^{\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor}(p-k)^{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}=(-1)^{\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^{k-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^{k-1}$$
Therefore
$$\prod_{1\le i<j\le \frac{p-1}{2}}(j^2-i^2)=\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^{\frac{p-1}{2}-1}=1$$

Comment: The author also uses the same proof to show that in case $p=1\pmod 4$ the product gives $-\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\pmod{p}$.